# Use chkrootkit and send status via ssmtp

Tags: chkrootkit

I installed

```
apt install chkrootkit
```

This seems to  run a cron job every day in `/etc/cron.daily/chkrootkit` which unfortunately will send its output into nirvana

I also installed a minimal mail dma:

```
apt install ssmpt
```

where I configured my mailserver as relay.

mail is working like

```
echo -e "Subject: Sent from a terminal\n\nHere the boidy | ssmtp receipient@email.de
```

But how do I setup chkrootkit so it sends an email?

Answer (score 0):

Since `chkrootkit` runs as `root`, the emailed output is sent to `root`. Use a "mail alias" to have `root`'s email delivered to you. Read `man 5 aliases` for details. On MY Ubuntu 16.04.05, MY `/etc/aliases` looks like:

```
# See man 5 aliases for format
postmaster:    root
root:    walt
```

That is, all of `postmaster`'s email is sent to `root`, and all of `root`'s email is sent to ME.

You MUST execute the `newaliases` command after changing `/etc/aliases` to make your changes take effect.